# Meaning of "that was Korea information" expression

Tags: expressions, slang

I'm currently negotiating with an UK resident and I have provided a big set of information.

My correspondant has answered me back "that was Korea information than I was expecting!".

I wonder if it is a mistake due to the smartphone auto-correction or if it's a real expression? if so, where does it comes from?

Comment: Likely a mistake. Probably attempted "more" but typed "kore", because the K and M are close together, resulting in an auto-correction of "Korea"

Comment: I would suggest you ask the person you are negotiating with what they mean by that. I have lived in the US and UK for extended periods of time and have never heard that expression. @Hank's explanation seems most likely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is most likely based on a typo and autocorrection as Hank said.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's a typo, I'm English and there's no such expression in th U.K.